# Fast idiomatic Floyd-Warshall algorithm in Rust

Tags: algorithm, rust, graph-algorithm

I am trying to implement a reasonably fast version of [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm in Rust. This algorithm finds a shortest paths between all vertices in a directed weighted graph.

The main part of the algorithm could be written like this:

```
// dist[i][j] contains edge length between vertices [i] and [j]
// after the end of the execution it contains shortest path between [i] and [j]
fn floyd_warshall(dist: &mut [Vec<i32>]) {
    let n = dist.len();
    for i in 0..n {
        for j in 0..n {
            for k in 0..n {
                dist[j][k] = min(dist[j][k], dist[j][i] + dist[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is very short and easy to understand, but it works 1.5x slower than similar c++ implementation.

As I understand problem is that on each vector access Rust checks that index is inside bounds of the vector, and it adds some overhead.

I rewrote this function with **get_unchecked*** functions:

```
fn floyd_warshall_unsafe(dist: &mut [Vec<i32>]) {
    let n = dist.len();
    for i in 0..n {
        for j in 0..n {
            for k in 0..n {
                unsafe {
                    *dist[j].get_unchecked_mut(k) = min(
                        *dist[j].get_unchecked(k),
                        dist[j].get_unchecked(i) + dist[i].get_unchecked(k),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it really started working 1.5x faster ([full code of the test](https://pastebin.com/0wXiCfwz)).

I didn't expect bounds check to add that much overhead :(

Is it possible to rewrite this code in an idiomatic way without unsafes, such that it works as fast as unsafe version? E.g. is it possible to "prove" to the compiler that there will be no out of bound access by adding some assertions to the code?

Comment: Are you wedded to the array of Vecs (or whatever that is)? My first thought would be to switch to a proper 2D array, or failing that, a 1D array with manual indexing. Then you might be able to convince the compiler to drop the bounds checks by asserting that the length of the 1D array is n*n.

Comment: Also, you are compiling with `--release`, right?

Comment: Yes, @Jmb, I am compiling in release mode.

Comment: As for @DavidEisenstat point - what is considered a proper 2D array in a Rust world? I tried [array2d](https://docs.rs/array2d/0.2.1/array2d/) crate, but it works even slower than Vec of vecs. I also implemented my own Array2D based on 1D vector inside [code](https://pastebin.com/Enb8nCRS), it works ~10% slower than unsafe version (which is what I would expect from one bounds check on each vector access), but it is much better than Vec of Vecs version!

Comment: I'm not a Rust programmer, so I don't know. Under the hood, LLVM doesn't seem to understand 2D arrays, and this C++ test program doesn't optimize as hoped, so I'm pessimistic about the prospects for answering this question: `#include <cassert> void test(int n) { assert(n >= 0); for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { assert(i + j < n + n); } } } `.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some experiments, based on ideas suggested in [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053798/7879087), and [comments in related issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/91109#issuecomment-974862503) I found solution, which:

- still uses the same interface (e.g. `&mut [Vec<i32>]` as argument)
- does't use unsafe
- 3-4x faster than unsafe version
- quite ugly :(

Code looks like this:

```
fn floyd_warshall_fast(dist: &mut [Vec<i32>]) {
    let n = dist.len();
    for i in 0..n {
        for j in 0..n {
            if i == j {
                continue;
            }
            let (dist_j, dist_i) = if j < i {
                let (lo, hi) = dist.split_at_mut(i);
                (&mut lo[j][..n], &mut hi[0][..n])
            } else {
                let (lo, hi) = dist.split_at_mut(j);
                (&mut hi[0][..n], &mut lo[i][..n])
            };
            let dist_ji = dist_j[i];
            for k in 0..n {
                dist_j[k] = min(dist_j[k], dist_ji + dist_i[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are couple of ideas inside:

- We compute `dist_ji` once as it doesn't change inside the most inner cycle, and compiler doesn't need to think about it.
- We "prove" that `dist[i]` and `dist[j]` are actually two different vectors. This is done by this ugly `split_at_mut` thing and `i == j` special case (would really love to know an easier solution). After that we can treat `dist[i]` and `dist[j]` absolutely separately, and for example the compiler can vectorize this loop, because it knows that data doesn't overlap.
- Last trick is to "prove" to the compiler that both `dist[i]` and `dist[j]` have at least `n` elements. This is done by `[..n]` when computing `dist[i]` and `dist[j]` (e.g. we use `&mut lo[j][..n]` instead of just `&mut lo[j]`). After that, compiler understands that the inner loop never uses out of bounds values, and removes checks.

Interesting that only when all three optimizations are used, it gives a big speed up. If we use only any two of them, the compiler can't optimize it.

Comment: Code appears to be written in an alien script :P, ask yourself if the optimization is worth the non-readability. Second-guessing or coercing a compiler into optimization is a known anti-pattern, makes for brittle code that breaks as compilers evolve.

Answer (score 5):

At first blush, one would hope this would be enough:

```
fn floyd_warshall(dist: &mut [Vec<i32>]) {
    let n = dist.len();
    for i in 0..n {
        assert!(i < dist.len());
        for j in 0..n {
            assert!(j < dist.len());
            assert!(i < dist[j].len());
            let v2 = dist[j][i];
            for k in 0..n {
                assert!(k < dist[i].len());
                assert!(k < dist[j].len());
                dist[j][k] = min(dist[j][k], v2 + dist[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding asserts is a known trick to convince the Rust optimizer that variables are indeed in bounds. However, it doesn't work here. What we need to do is somehow make it even more obvious to the Rust compiler that these loops are in bounds without resorting to esoteric code.

To accomplish that, I moved to a 2D array as suggested by David Eisenstat:

```
fn floyd_warshall<const N:usize>(mut dist: Box<[[i32; N]; N]>) -> Box<[[i32; N]; N]> {
    for i in 0..N {
        for j in 0..N {
            for k in 0..N {
                dist[j][k] = min(dist[j][k], dist[j][i] + dist[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    dist
}
```

This uses constant generics, a relatively new feature of Rust, to specify the size of a given 2d array on the heap. On its own, this change does well on my machine (100ms faster than usafe, and ~20ms behind unsafe). If, additionally, you move the v2 calculation outside the k-loop like this:

```
fn floyd_warshall<const N:usize>(mut dist: Box<[[i32; N]; N]>) -> Box<[[i32; N]; N]> {
    for i in 0..N {
        for j in 0..N {
            let v2 = dist[j][i];
            for k in 0..N {
                dist[j][k] = min(dist[j][k], v2 + dist[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    dist
}
```

The improvement is substantial (from ~300ms to ~100ms on my machine). The same optimization works with `floyd_warshall_unsafe` bringing it to ~100ms on average on my machine. When inspecting the assembly (with `#[inline(never)]` on floyd_warshall) it doesn't look like bounds checks occur for either, and both look vectorized to some extent. Although, I am no expert at reading assembly.

Because this is such a hot loop (with up to three bounds checks) I'm not surprised performance suffers so much. Unfortunately, the usage of the indices in this case is complicated enough to prevent the assert trick from giving you an easy fix. There are other known cases where an assert check is desired to improve the performance but the compiler is unable to use the information sufficiently. [Here is one such example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71997).

[Here is the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b3a6cf4259a4e5c7a4577fb457e6d7a1) with my changes.

Comment: Wow, this `let v2 = dist[j][i]` really makes it much faster! Probably compiler realizes we do similar stuff for all `k`, and is able to vectorize the code.

Comment: I agree that constant generics helps here to eliminate bounds checks, but it seems a little unpractical, because it will not work if we don't know size of the graph in compile time, right?

Comment: Note that the asserts are wrong because they check all three variables against the length of the outer vector (`dist`) but not against the length of the inner vectors, but there is no obvious reasons why they should be the same. So you should assert that `i < dist.len()`, `j < dist.len()`, `i < dist[j].len()`, `k < dist[i].len()` and `k < dist[j].len()`.

Comment: Good point @Jmb, I fixed the code and tested it again, unfortunately it still doesn't elide the bounds checks.

Comment: @Borys It is true that you need to know the size of the array at compile time. In that respect the unsafe code is more practical. If you really wanted to use the const generic code you would need to pick concrete sizes and fit your graph into that size to use. One approach you might want to consider is using [Prusti](https://github.com/viperproject/prusti-dev) to add contracts for semantic comments that you aren't accessing outside of bounds